# reading specified column in excel using python

Tags: python, excel

So i need to output everything under a column name using python.

so far i can read in entire excel file. in my workbook i have many data sheets so i specfited which one to open, now i just need to only ouput everything under a specifyed column. Here is my code

```
import xlrd

file_Location = "/home/jerad/Desktop/Register.xlsx"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_Location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('CM4000 Register View')
num_rows = sheet.nrows - 1
curr_row = -1
while curr_row < num_rows:
   curr_row += 1
   row = sheet.row(curr_row)   #this is print everything in the file.
   print row
```

Answer (score 0):

Update like:

```
while curr_row < num_rows:
    curr_row += 1
    row = sheet.cell(curr_row,1)   #this is print only the cells selected (Index Start from 0).
    print (row.value)
```

If you print only **row**, you have something like:

```
number:1.0
```

When you use **.value** you have only the value:

```
1.0
```